# counting the no. of rows with empty values of specific columns only

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I am creating an android app.In which I have a database table having no.of columns.
From those columns i am selecting 4 specific columns and checking whether there are null or empty values in it.
it should give me the count of the no.of rows in which there are empty values.
the code i used is

```
count=db.rawQuery("select * from "+AllValuesTable+" where (app_salutation IS NULL OR app_salutation='') AND (ref_cusagreeno IS NULL or ref_cusagreeno='') AND (asset_categry IS NULL or asset_categry='') AND (off_Applcname IS NULL or off_Applcname='');", null).getCount();
```

but the output i am getting is 0 whereas it should display 4....because there are four rows in which these columns are empty.
i cant seem to figure out the problem.
pls help.
thanks!

Comment: Are all the conditions meant to met per row of data or is only one column able to be empty to satisfy your condition?

Comment: the condition has to be met in every row.

Answer (score 0):

On the possibility that you have spaces it may be worth trimming your fileds before comparing to `''` :

```
count=db.rawQuery
  (
   "select * from "+AllValuesTable+" where 
   (app_salutation IS NULL OR TRIM(app_salutation)='') AND
   (ref_cusagreeno IS NULL OR TRIM(ref_cusagreeno)='') AND
   (asset_categry IS NULL OR TRIM(asset_categry)='') AND
   (off_Applcname IS NULL OR TRIM(off_Applcname)='')"
  , null).getCount();
```

Comment: if i use this statement `select app_salutation from "+AllValuesTable+" where app_salutation IS NULL OR TRIM(app_salutation)=''", null).getCount(); `   it is giving me the correct count..but here only one column is selected which is not my requirement....

Comment: So all columns in Where must be essentially empty.. I honestly don't see anything wrong with the syntax so I would sanity check the data.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know why your query did not throw an exception, the document is not very clear what would happen if the sql statement is invalid. In any case you should not end your statement with a semicolon.

```
Official document
```

> Parameters
>   sql the SQL query. The SQL string must not be ; terminated

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], android.os.CancellationSignal)